# Need assistance with a for loop in Tic Tac Toe game

Tags: c++, oop

My program is exiting without iterating. It automatically goes to "YOU WON". Without the champion function the program runs fine. Its probably some obvious error Im missing. If anyone could please I would greatly appreciate it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define GRID_SIZE 3

class TicTacToe {
private:
    char map[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE];

public:

    void champion() {
        const char *possiblities[8]{
                "123"
                "456"
                "789"
                "147"
                "159"
                "258"
                "369"
                "753"
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            bool winner = true;
            char previous_pos = '0';
            const char *possible_moves = possiblities[i];

            for (int index = 0; index < GRID_SIZE; index++) {
                char character = possible_moves[i];
                int entered_num = character - '0';
                int grid_space = entered_num - 1;
                int row = index / GRID_SIZE;
                int col = index % GRID_SIZE;

                char grid_coordinate = map[row][col];

                if (previous_pos == '0') {
                    previous_pos = grid_coordinate;
                } else if
                        (previous_pos == grid_coordinate) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    winner = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (winner = true) {
                std::cout << "YOU WON" << std::endl;
                exit(0);
                break;
            }

        }


    }

    void playgame() {
        std::string input;

        while (true) {
            std::cout << "Go player one" << std::endl;
            getline(std::cin, input);
            if (input != " ") {
                char entered = input.c_str()[0];

                if (entered >= '1' && entered <= '9') {
                    int entered_num = entered - '0';
                    int index = entered_num - 1;
                    int row = index / 3;
                    int col = index % 3;
                    char grid_position = map[row][col];

                    if (grid_position == 'X' || grid_position == 'O') {
                        std::cout << "Space taken. Try again" << std::endl;
                    } else {
                        map[row][col] = (char) 'X';
                        break;
                    }

                } else {
                    std::cout << "Only numbers 1 - 9" << std::endl;
                }
            } else {
                std::cout << "Have to enter something, try again" << std::endl;
            }


        }
    }

    void generateGrid() {
        int number = 1;

        for (int x = 0; x < GRID_SIZE; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < GRID_SIZE; y++) {
                map[x][y] = std::to_string(number).c_str()[0];
                number += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    void tictacToeMap() {


        std::cout << std::endl;

        for (int x = 0; x < GRID_SIZE; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < GRID_SIZE; y++) {
                std::printf(" %c ", map[x][y]);
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }

    }


    TicTacToe() {
        generateGrid();
        while (true) {
            tictacToeMap();
            playgame();
            champion();


        }
    }
};


int main() {

    TicTacToe tic;
    tic.playgame();


    return 0;


}
```

Comment: `if (winner = true)` -> `if (winner == true)` or just `if (winner)`. I'd really recommend learning to use your debugger. It'll make things like that very easy to spot, and let you solve pretty much any bug on your own.

Comment: Without looking too thoroughly, `if (winner = true)` looks like a problem.

Comment: You usually get a message from the compiler over mistakes like this. Compiler warnings are the first line of defense against trivial mistakes like this. If you aren't getting a warning, crank up the compiler's warning level (I use -pedantic -Wall -Wextra with gcc)  and enjoy the extra spare time they bring.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```cpp
if (winner = true) {
                std::cout << "YOU WON" << std::endl;
                exit(0);
                break;
            }
```

You probably meant:

```cpp
if (winner == true) {
                std::cout << "YOU WON" << std::endl;
                exit(0);
                break;
            }
```

Comment: this still exits the program immediately -> if (winner ) {
                std::cout << "YOU WON" << std::endl;
                exit(0);
                break;
            }

Answer (score 0):

First, do what Max Meijer said, by replacing `if(winner = true)` with `if(winner == true)`. But the program is still broken. The problem is that in your string array, you are not separating each string with a comma, so when my debugger hits `const char *possible_moves`, it ends up just assigning the entire array concatenated together. So just separate each string in the possibilities array with a comma, like so:

```
const char *possiblities[8]{
                "123",
                "456",
                "789",
                "147",
                "159",
                "258",
                "369",
                "753"
        };
```

Comment: Thank you so much Dylan!